# What is meant by the term "quantum interference"?

Tags: terminology-and-notation

What is meant by the term "quantum interference" in the context of quantum computing and quantum algorithms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term is most often used in the context of the [two-slit experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#Interference_of_individual_particles). The interference pattern that you see, which is not simply what you'd get if you added the wavefunction ($\Psi_A$) associated with going through slit A to the wavefunction ($\Psi_B$) going through slit B, but there is a "mixed" term as follows:

$$
\tag{1}
|\psi|^2 = |\psi_A + \psi_B|^2 = |\psi_A|^2 +  |\psi_B|^2 + \psi_A^*\psi_B + \psi_A\psi_B^*.
$$

This interference pattern occurs **even when you reduce the number of photons until there's only one photon at a time!** When there's only one photon at a time, what could it possibly be interfering with to cause the patter on the screen to be different from $P_A + P_B$?

**We say the photon interferes with itself.** This is a quantum mechanical phenomenon that doesn't exist in classical mechanics.

The two-slit experiment was used by Feynman when he explained the Feynman integral, because the Feynman integral is a sum/integral over paths which each have an amplitude. These amplitudes ***interfere*** with each other, which again is a signature of quantum mechanical effects, since classically there would only be one path in the Feynman integral: the path with the smallest Lagrangian action.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Are you saying that *quantum interference* has no meaning in quantum computing, and this term is (and should) be used in the context of quantum physics?

Comment: It doesn't have "no meaning" in quantum computing. The meaning is the same here. For example the Mach-Zender ***interfer***ometer is frequently used to explain the concept of superposition of qubits for a photonic quantum computer: Without interference, there's no quantum computer.

Comment: Whoa.  Been reading a tiny bit and I actually understood that.  Thank you for that point about Mach-Zender interferometer! Highly instructive. I want to learn more about self interference. The symbol |Ψ|² makes sense to me, as does your equation. I really like the clear way math is written in this field.